# Showing that a bijection preserves homomorphism

Tags: logic

I have the vocabulary $\tau = \{+, 0 \}$ and the structure $R = (\mathbb{R}, +^R, 0^R)$ where $+^R$ is a binary function symbol representing the normal addition of numbers and $0^R$ is the constant $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. I 'm trying to prove that the bijection $$\sigma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ with } \sigma(x) = -x$$

is an automorphism of $R$.

What I (think I) only need to show: the homomorphism property for each function symbol, in this case  $$+^R : \sigma (x +^R y) = \sigma(x) +^R \sigma(y) \ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$$ holds. We don't need to worry about $0$, since it's covered by our bijection's definition.

So, the homomorphism property seems to work for every $x$ and $y$ I pick, for example:

$$\sigma(1+^R1) = \sigma(2) = \sigma(1) +^R \sigma(1) = -1 +^R -1 = -2$$

$$\sigma(2+^R1) = \sigma(3) = \sigma(2) +^R \sigma(1) = -2 +^R -1 = -3$$

etc.

We can't prove by induction because we're not working in $\mathbb{N}$. Can anyone show me or give me a hint how I can formally prove this for all numbers in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol $0^{\mathbb R}$ is a 0-ary function symbol, and you need to handle it as well. Since $-0 = 0$, this is not a problem.

As for $+^{\mathbb R}$, high school arithmetic shows that
$$
-(x+y) = (-x) + (-y).
$$

More generally, $-$ is an automorphism of any Abelian group. An Abelian group is a set together with a binary operator $+$, a unary operator $-$, and a constant $0$ such that:

1. $x+y = y+x$.
2. $(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)$.
3. $x+0 = x$.
4. $x+(-x) = 0$.

The mapping $x \mapsto -x$ is an automorphism. Notice that

- For all $x$, $(-x)+x=x+(-x)=0$.
- For all $x$, $(-x)+(-(-x))=0$.
- Hence $x = x+0 = x+((-x)+(-(-x))) = (x+(-x))+(-(-x)) = 0+(-(-x)) = (-(-x))+0 = -(-x)$.

Therefore $-$ is an involution. In particular, if $-x=-y$ then $x=-(-x)=-(-y)=y$, so that $-$ is one-to-one. Since $-(-x)=x$, it is also onto.

Since $0 = 0 + (-0) = (-0) + 0 = -0$, we see that $-$ maps $0$ to itself.

Since $-(-x) = -(-x)$, we see that $-$ maps $-$ to itself.

Finally,
$$
(x+y)+((-x)+(-y)) = (y+x)+((-x)+(-y)) = ((y+x)+(-x))+(-y) = (y+(x+(-x)))+(-y) = (y+0)+(-y) = y+(-y) = 0.
$$
Therefore
$$
-(x+y) = (-(x+y)) + 0 = (-(x+y)) + ((x+y)+((-x)+(-y))) = ((-(x+y))+(x+y)) + ((-x)+(-y)) = ((x+y)+(-(x+y))) + ((-x)+(-y)) = 0 + ((-x)+(-y)) = ((-x)+(-y)) + 0 = (-x)+(-y).
$$
This shows that $-$ maps $+$ to itself.